# The API /tag stats are notably different from the site totals

Tags: support, bug, tags, api-v2.2, caching

Why this discrepancy?

```
--Sep 10 2015 11:26:09 GMT+0530 (IST)--
```

- At that time, [the API shows **42010** tags](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&filter=!9YdnSQVoS&site=stackoverflow&run=true).
- But the same thing computed on [the Stack Overflow tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) is **44496**.

Is it because of caching?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 2 or 3 effects, the biggest is that **[the *Tags* page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) also shows Synonyms.**

There may also be a *small* cache effect, but there seems to be another discrepancy as well, possibly an error/bug.

---

You can see that **the *Tags* page also shows Synonyms** by:

1. Go to [the Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).
2. Enter `userscr` in the *Type to find tags:* box.
3. You will see something like:
   [image: It's not real!]
4. Then use the Synonyms pages to see that [`userscript` is a synonym of `userscripts`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/synonyms), not a real tag.
5. [The API call](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&inname=userscr&filter=!9YdnSQVoS&site=stackoverflow&run=true) reflects this.

---

**Combining the API's [`/tags` route](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#order=desc&sort=popular&filter=!%29V%29MSZJUTLp&site=stackoverflow&run=true) and [the `/tags/synonyms` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tag-synonyms#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!%29V%29MSZJUTLp&site=stackoverflow&run=true)**, I currently get:

```
42020 + 2442 = 44462
```

If you count up all the tags on the *Tags* page(s), I currently get:

```
     4 columns
*    9 rows
* 1236 pages
+   10 on the last page (page 1237)
-----------------------------------
44,506
```

**Which *still* gives a discrepancy of 44!**

This is too big to be explained by caching.  The Tags page seems almost real-time and the API count is updating at least once an hour.

[The latest SEDE data is *currently* from Sep 6 at 6:11](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (about 4 days ago) and SEDE shows that [there were 44,377 tags + active synonyms at that time.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/362433/total-number-of-tags-and-active-tag-synomyms)

This suggests a growth rate of about 32 tags per day, or about 1.3 tags per hour -- which matches the observed increase in the API results.

This final discrepancy (44) is something else; **quite possibly a bug.**

---

Cross checking [the *Tag Synonyms* page(s), set to the `active` tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?page=25&tab=newest&filter=active) gives:

```
    24 pages
*  100 Synonyms per page
+   42 on the last page (page 25)
-----------------------------------
  2442
```

Which agrees with [the API result](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tag-synonyms#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!%29V%29MSZJUTLp&site=stackoverflow&run=true).